# Regarding GPU mode error in launching Android virtual device

Tags: android, android-studio, gpu, android-virtual-device, mesa

When I am trying to launch Android virtual device in Android Studio 2.0, it is giving me following error.

**ERROR: Invalid GPU mode 'mesa', use one of: on off host guest**

A screen shot is given bellow related to this error:
[image: Error]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!Thanks.....

Comment: Have you tried deleting the virtual device and re-creating it?

Comment: Yes,i tried.Even i uninstalled Android Studio completely and reinstalled it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Go to Virtual device manager, click 'Show on Disk' in the menu of the Virtual device. Open the *config.ini* file and change the respective line to:
**hw.gpu.mode=guest**
Then save the *config.ini* and then run Virtual device again. It should work.

Comment: I recently changed my OS.Now it's working fine.If someone get help from your answer,i will mark it as accepted answer.Thanks.

Comment: This is the only solution that works for me.  (automatic mode choses hardware graphics, which are currently not working.)

Comment: Worked for me on Android Studio 2.3.3 and Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS x64.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same error and what worked for me was : Open AVD manager as in the screenshot in the question. Then click on Edit this AVD on the right. After the configuration window opens, there is a setting for Graphics in Emulated Performance. I set it to Auto which solved the error for me.

Comment: Just Setting it to Automatic  work for me ...Thanks @user3814327

Comment: This do not work for me on Android Studio 2.3.3 and Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS x64.

Answer (score 1):

A one-liner to disable GPU for all installed AVDs:

```
find  ~/.android/avd/ -name config.ini | while read f; do sed -ibak 's/hw.gpu.mode=.*/hw.gpu.mode=off/' "$f"; done
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error. As a work-around I created another virtual device (AVD) with the same configuration and then used that device as my Emulator. That fixed it.
Click on the "Create Virtual Device" button shown in the screenshot.

You can also try changing the configuration of the virtual device to find which one works best for your app.