# Android emulator not starting in ubuntu

Tags: android, ubuntu, android-emulator

Android emulator not starting with Ubuntu,Below is the error log obtained when running the emulator, the emulator starts and closes immediately.
I m using ubuntu 16.10, and android studio version 2.3.1

```
libGL error: unable to load driver: i965_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: i965
libGL error: unable to load driver: i965_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: i965
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
X Error of failed request:  GLXBadContext
  Major opcode of failed request:  155 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  6 (X_GLXIsDirect)
  Serial number of failed request:  55
  Current serial number in output stream:  54
libGL error: unable to load driver: i965_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: i965
libGL error: unable to load driver: i965_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: i965
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
X Error of failed request:  GLXBadContext
  Major opcode of failed request:  155 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  6 (X_GLXIsDirect)
  Serial number of failed request:  55
  Current serial number in output stream:  54
libGL error: unable to load driver: i965_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: i965
libGL error: unable to load driver: i965_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: i965
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  155 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  24 (X_GLXCreateNewContext)
  Value in failed request:  0x0
  Serial number of failed request:  39
  Current serial number in output stream:  40
QObject::~QObject: Timers cannot be stopped from another thread
[1]    13209 segmentation fault  ./emulator -avd Nexus_5X_API_26
```

Comment: Can you run the command `glxinfo | grep "OpenGL version"` and tell what is the output of it?

Comment: same issue on Ubuntu 17.04 with Intel Linux drivers, glxinfo shows "OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 17.0.7"

Answer (score 4):

Source: [Android Studio 2.3 Ubuntu 16.10 emulator do not start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42831999/android-studio-2-3-ubuntu-16-10-emulator-do-not-start)

```
sudo apt-get install lib64stdc++6:i386
sudo apt-get install mesa-utils
```

(look for the path of the sdk)

```
cd YOURPATH/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64
mv libstdc++/ libstdc++.bak
ln -s /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6  libstdc++
```

Finally, run your application again using emulator.

Comment: Find YOURPATH with `find $ANDROID_HOME -name "libstdc++"`