# Android Studio 2.3.3. ,Unable to launch Emulator

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator

Well,i am trying to launch the emulator in android studio 2.3.3  ,the project is running ,but i am not able to see the virtual device ,anyone can help with this?

Answer (score 1):

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44562324/801151) on SO, which deals with the same problem on Ubuntu. As you did not specify the operating system you are using, I'm not sure whether this will actually help you, but maybe it can point you in the right direction.

The answer linked above recommends adding the following line to the startup script (which is called `studio.sh` and located in the `bin` directory underneath the Android Studio directory, at least it does for Linux):

```
# Preload shared library required by Android emulator
export LD_PRELOAD='/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6'
```

That worked perfectly for me, maybe it can help you too?

Good luck!